# 7mm drive in 9.5mm HDD bay - Causing loud humming noise?

Tags: hard-drive

Ive got a 7mm drive in a 9.5mm HDD bay and it appears to be causing loud humming noises when the drive is in operation. Ive narrowed it down to the bay as this occurs with two different HDDs.

As you can see in this pic, the drive, even when fully slotted in, is capable of "bending" a bit and i think that's what is causing the noise.

Does anyone know if there's a way to get the drive to stay firmly seated in a 9.5mm bay?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have 7mm Intel SSD. It was shipped with some kind of plastic frame.

It looks like this:

[image]

(I took image from: [link](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5508/intel-ssd-520-review-cherryville-brings-reliability-to-sandforce/2))

---

Maybe you can use this?

`Lenovo 7mm to 9.5mm hdd rubber rail (part number 04W1640)`:

[image]

(image source: [link to ebay.com](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Original-genuine-Thinkpad-lenovo-IBM-7mm-to-9-5mm-hdd-rubber-rail-04W1640-new-/181412528863?pt=US_Drive_Bay_Caddies&hash=item2a3d0782df))

---

You can try to make some kind of hand-made 2.5mm adapter but do not put paper or something else on whole area of disk to fill up the space - it needs cooling, and some materials may work like thermal insulation and keep heat inside disk. This is why my Intel SSD has just frame and Lenovo uses rails instead of some kind of 2.5mm plate.

Comment: Unfortunately my laptop isnt a lenovo one so i dont think those rubber rails would work. Where would i be able to get frames like the intel one?

Comment: I was looking on ebay for something like frame from my Intel SSD, but I couldn't find anything. I think Lenovo rubber rails may fit any laptop, they are not that expensive, you can try.

Comment: If your disk in these rubber rails will be too wide - you can use knife and remove some rubber on sides.

Comment: How are you supposed to use the rubber pads aynway? Which sides do they go onto?

Comment: You put them on sides (longer edges). Extra 2.5mm goes to top of disk (side with label).